# Install custom ToolTipManager

Tags: java, swing, tooltip, custom-component

I would like to extend the `ToolTipManager` to have a custom look and behavior.

Two problems:

1. To extend the class I have to create the child in the same package
   (the constuctor of `ToolTipManager` has package visibility).
2. I have to force force java to use my own tooltip manager. I don't
   know how...

Is there any way to use our own custom `ToolTipManager`?

In fact I found a solution, but I don't like it:

1. Create a new class `ToolTipManager` with the same fullname (same
   package `javax.swing`).
2. Pack this class in a jar.
3. Use the option `-Xbootclasspath/p` to force the classloader to load my jar first, so to use my class `javax.swing.ToolTipManager`

Comment: astonished that you could create a class in javax.swing - always thought that's heavily secured?

Comment: No you can create it and use it without problem.